# Function to replace word in textfile not working as intended

Tags: c

I have a function that parses each word on a line and if a word that matches is found, it will replace it, which must be done via a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        FILE * fp;
        FILE * tmp;
        size_t line=0;
        char file[100];
        char buf[1000];
        char wordOne[20];
        char wordTwo[20];
        sscanf(argv[1], "%s", file);            //get file(path) into variable
        sscanf(argv[2], "%s", wordOne);         //get searched word into variable
        sscanf(argv[3], "%s", wordTwo);         //get replacing word into variable
        fp  = fopen(file, "r");                 //open old file
        tmp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");           //open temporary file
        while ((fgets(buf, 1000, fp)) != NULL){
                char *token = strtok(buf, " "); //split line
                for (int cnt = 0; token != NULL; cnt++) {               //iterate through fields
                        fputs(sub(token, wordOne, wordTwo),tmp);    // Check word and write to temp file
                        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }
                if (strchr (buf, '\n')) line++; // increment line
        }
        fclose(fp);                     //close old file
        fclose(tmp);                    //close temp file
        remove(file);                   //delete original file
        rename("temp.txt", file);       //rename temporary file
    return 0;
}
const char* sub(char testW[], char wO[], char wT[]){
        if(strcmp(testW,wO) == 0){ //if word tested matchech word1
                return wT;              //return word2
        } else {                //if not
                return wO;              //return word1
        }

}
```

For example, if I call it using "./a.out test.txt bob joe" with test.txt having

```
Hello
Nice to meet you
My name is bob
```

it's supposed to return

```
Hello
Nice to meet you
My name is joe
```

but instead, it just returns

```
bobbobbobbobbobbobbobbobbob
```

I don't understand where my mistakes are or how to fix it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change this `return wO;` to `return testW;` maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(strcmp(testW,wO) == 0){ //if word tested matchech word1
                return wT;              //return word2
        } else {                //if not
                return wO;              //return word1
        }
```

This piece of code will only return `wT` or `wO`, no matter it matches or not. Since your `wO` is `"bob"`, it will return `"bob"` for every non-matching token, and therefore the output is `"bobbobbob..."`. To fix that, replace it with

```
        if(strcmp(testW,wO) == 0){ //if word tested matchech word1
                return wT;              //return word2
        } else {                //if not
                return testW;              //return word1
        }
```

Also notice that you need to output an additional `" "` after outputting the token. Replace

```
fputs(sub(token, wordOne, wordTwo),tmp);
```

with

```
fputs(sub(token, wordOne, wordTwo),tmp);
fputs(" ",tmp);
```